# Storing Datatable in cache, all users see it?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Just want to double check something.  I have the following code:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Cache["DataTable"] == null)
{
     Cache.Insert("DataTable", DtMaster, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2),
           System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
}
```

Say user A logs in and creates a datatable containing 3 rows, if user B then logged on to a completely machine would they also see 3 rows?

I guess I'm asking does items stored in the cache become available to all users?

Thanks.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.cache(v=vs.110).aspx - in particular *There is one instance of the Cache class per application domain. As a result, the Cache object that is returned by the Cache property is the Cache object for all requests in the application domain.*. You should use a session instead, if you want to isolate the data between users.

Comment: Yes. `HttpContext.Cache` is global and shared across requests, unlike `Session`. Also, storing an entire `DataTable` in cache (per user) doesn't sound like a good idea regardless of storage

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

> There is one instance of the Cache class per application domain. As a
>   result, the Cache object that is returned by the Cache property is the
>   Cache object for all requests in the application domain.

[HttpContext.Cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.cache(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
It will work for multi user's, Please don't forget to Reset the cache in case of any change is happening in db which is related to this datatable records.